# Unable to connect to Cluster IP of a service inside Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to follow this course https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6WC5n9G_sM&t=5478s on Kubernetes.  I created a deployment and I have 3 pods running nginx.
I can access every pod individually but I cannot access the whole service with the cluster IP and the exposed port within Minikube.
I have no idea what it can be as I am following the exact steps as in the video. Maybe someone could spot the problem?
Thank you!!!!!!!

```html
ejandro@alejandro-Latitude-7390:~$ kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   38d
alejandro@alejandro-Latitude-7390:~$ kubectl describe service kubernetes
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.96.0.1
IPs:               10.96.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        8443/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.59.100:8443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
alejandro@alejandro-Latitude-7390:~$ kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   38d
alejandro@alejandro-Latitude-7390:~$ kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --port=80 --target-port=80
service/nginx-deployment exposed
alejandro@alejandro-Latitude-7390:~$ kubectl get service
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   38d
nginx-deployment   ClusterIP   10.98.250.240   <none>        80/TCP    3s
alejandro@alejandro-Latitude-7390:~$ kubectl describe service nginx-deployment
Name:              nginx-deployment
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=nginx-deployment
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=nginx-deployment
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.98.250.240
IPs:               10.98.250.240
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.3:80,172.17.0.4:80,172.17.0.5:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
alejandro@alejandro-Latitude-7390:~$ sudo ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no docker@192.168.59.100 
[sudo] password for alejandro: 
docker@192.168.59.100's password: 
                         _             _            
            _         _ ( )           ( )           
  ___ ___  (_)  ___  (_)| |/')  _   _ | |_      __  
/' _ ` _ `\| |/' _ `\| || , <  ( ) ( )| '_`\  /'__`\
| ( ) ( ) || || ( ) || || |\`\ | (_) || |_) )(  ___/
(_) (_) (_)(_)(_) (_)(_)(_) (_)`\___/'(_,__/'`\____)

$ curl 10.98.250.240:80
^C
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with `kubectl expose ...` but this isn't going to work with Minikube since the porting in Minikube is set up differently. Instead, with docker up, run:

```
minikube service <SERVICE-NAME>
```

This is just Minikube specific but when working on a non-minikube K8 Cluster , it is `kubectl expose...` Also, `ClusterIP` service type is used for network traffic INSIDE the cluster but for debugging/testing, exposing it is fine. The other service objects like `NodePort` and `LoadBalancer` are designed for external internet traffic.

Comment: Hi, i did minikube service <SERVICE-NAME> but it did not work. I reinstalled minikube and now it is working. thank you.

Comment: Glad its working now! After reinstalling, did 'Minikube service' work or 'kubectl expose'?